# Not partitioned index on partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

When I have partitioned table in Oracle database, Is it possible not to use partitioned index on it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, sure.  You can have a [global nonpartitioned index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm#460722).  Having global indexes, though, often creates headaches particularly when your partitioning scheme is designed to facilitate the easy loading or archiving of data since various partition operations require extra work to update the global indexes.